# Stack around the variable 'n' was corrupted? C++ VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stack

So I'm working on a college project where I need to create a linked list of 'Structures'. and when I'm adding a new element to the linked list I get this error, which is weird because I am not even using the stack while doing it.
 Here's how 'Structure' is defined:

```
#ifndef Structure_h
#define Structure_h
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
class Structure
{
public:
    int Integer;
    stack <int> s;
};

#endif
```

Definition of node:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h
using namespace std;
#include "Structure.h"
class Node
{
public:
    Node();
    Structure Str;
    Node *next;
};

#endif
```

LinkedList.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef LinkedList_h
#define LinkedList_h
using namespace std;
#include "Node.h"
class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    int size;
    void add(int a);
    Node *Current;
    Node *Start;
};

#endif
```

LinkedList.cpp:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    Node FirstNode;
    Start = Current = &FirstNode;
    cout << "Start = " << Start->Str.Integer << endl;
    cout << "Current = " << Current->Str.Integer << endl;
}
void LinkedList::add(int a)
{
    Node n;
    n.Str.Integer = a;
    Current->next = &n;
    Current = Current->next;
    cout << Current->Str.Integer;
}
```

Now whenever I create a new LinkedList and adding something to it I get this error.
I got a feeling like I'm using the Stack wrong somehow, not sure why though.
Thank you from advance.

Comment: In your LinkedList constructor Start and Current are initialized with a pointer to local variable, they will be pointing to garbage when constructor returns.

Comment: `I got a feeling like I'm using the Stack wrong somehow`: I believe you're thinking about the `stack<int> s` in your code, but this is *not* the stack that the error is talking about. There is another stack called the "call stack" that provides a place to put local temporary variables (among other things). The answers below talk about adding a local variable to your list and then returning from the function. The local variable you're adding to the list is in the call stack, and writes to that location will corrupt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this method:

```
void LinkedList::add(int a)
{
    Node n;
    n.Str.Integer = a;
    Current->next = &n;
    Current = Current->next;
    cout << Current->Str.Integer;
}
```

you are adding as `next` local variable `n`, it will get destroyed once `add` returns. This is undefined behaviour. You should use `Node* n = new Node;`, dont forget to deallocate.

[edit]

The same applies to other places in your code where you take a pointer to local variable and store it as a list node.

Comment: **** me, could spend the whole day looking for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
void LinkedList::add(int a)
{
    Node n;
    n.Str.Integer = a;

    Current->next = &n;
    // Here, you are storing a pointer to a local variable.
    // The pointer becomes a dangling pointer when the function returns.


    Current = Current->next;
    cout << Current->Str.Integer;
}
```

Use a dynamically allocated `Node`.

```
void LinkedList::add(int a)
{
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->Str.Integer = a;
    Current->next = n;
    Current = Current->next;
    cout << Current->Str.Integer;
}
```